# Which formatter is used when I send a multipart request to a Web API Controller in ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

Checking the ASP.NET Core [built-in formatters](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters) there seems to be no multipart formatter. Yet a multipart request is model bound, so there needs to be some kind of input formatter, that creates the key-value pairs, which are then model bound. Which formatter is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model is bound during [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Model binder in its turn uses `IValueProvider` to get values from request. There is [FormValueProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/FormValueProvider.cs) for multipart content, which in its turn gets values from [FormValueProviderFactory](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/FormValueProviderFactory.cs) provided by [request.ReadFormAsync()](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/FormValueProviderFactory.cs#L45) call. Default implementation of `HttpRequest` redirects the call to [FormFeature](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Http/Http/src/Features/FormFeature.cs)'s [ReadFormAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Http/Http/src/Features/FormFeature.cs#L126). So you can find all the logic for reading multipart content values there.

Comment: thanks for that detailed answer, highly appreciated!